# Python script that increases a number by a percent and then with a new number till goal

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, loops, operators

I found this problem and wanted to try to execute, but got stuck:

*Compile a program that allows you to determine how many days will be enough for 200 something if consumed on the first day 5 tons, but every next day 20% more than the previous day.*

In Python, using loop operators, lists and
functions.

I tried with the def function, but I don't know if it's correct and I don't know how to get it so that when it increases by 20%, the new number increases by 20%, so all the time with new numbers until it reaches 200

```
def day():
    x=5
    x += (x * 20/100)
    print(x)
day()
```

it is just a half, i know.

Comment: You need a loop that keeps running until you have 200 something.

Comment: You can use a while-loop with `while consumation <=200:` that then repeats your code. Also you need to track the total consumation and the daily consumation that you raise by 20% each day separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function a single time, basically X is incrementing once and then not being referenced again. To increment X until you reach a value >= 200, you would need to use a `while` loop. Code could look like this:

```
x = 5
dayscount = 1
while x < 200:
   print(x)
   print(dayscount)
   dayscount = dayscount + 1
   x = x * (1+(20/100))
```

you dont necessarily need to define within a function either, but if you did, you would need to define x outside the function and make it a global variable.

Comment: Note: see that X is incremented by x * (1 + (20/100))... if you just tried x * (20/100) it would actually take 20% of X... the numbers would get smaller.

Answer (score 1):

## Declaring Needed Variables

```
numberOfDays = 0 
totalTons = 200
dayTonsUsed = 5
```

## Consuming the tons and modifying the variables

```
while (totalTons > 0):
    totalTons -= dayTonsUsed
    dayTonsUsed *= 1.2 # Adding extra 20% of consumption for the next day 
    numberOfDays += 1
```

## Getting total days

```
print(f"Number of days needed {numberOfDays} days")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The solution which you're trying to implement, is very close, but you're not actually adding the values from day. You want something like the following:

```
def day(x):
    return x + (x * 20/100)

x = 5
currentSum = x
day = 1
while(currentSum < 200): # Loop until the amount consumed is more than 200
    x = day(x)
    currentSum += x
    day += 1

print(day)
```

Note, there is a faster mathematical solution, but it is not necessary for this problem since all the numbers are fairly small.

Answer (score 0):

with recursion it could be done this way:

```
def day(n, x=5):
    return 1 + day(n-x, x*1.2) if n>0 else 0

day(200)  # 13
```